# smart gwt event notification after drop is totally completed

Tags: smartgwt

I have an HStack with some IButton. I can move the Buttons in the HStack with darg & drop. Now a want to have an notification after the IButton is finally integrated in the HStack after drop. I'd like to determine the position of the dragged button in the HStack. 
All I found was a DropHander (for the Hstack) and DragRepositionStopHandler (for the Buttons). Both will fire events after the mouse button is released. At his moment the the button is not in the HStack. 
My question is: Is there an EventHander there will fire a event after an item is added to a Layout widget?

Thanks in advance.

Medrod

Comment: Aren't getX() and getY() methods, from the DropEvent, enough to get the position of where the IButton landed? Also, I do not understand what you mean the IButton is not part of the HStack. If it is a member before you drag it, it should remain member after you drop it. In any case inside the DropHandler you can also add the IButton as a member of the HStack, if it is required.

Comment: getX() getY() gives the position of the mouse.

Comment: @gpapaz at dropping the button, the button will be removed from the HStack (drop container) and after dropping added again to the HStack.

Answer (score 0):

After the DropEvent is fired, your Button is in position and about to become member of the HStack. Nothing can actually stop this. So when you receive this event all you have to do at the HStack is to retrieve the source of the event and call its getAbsoluteLeft and getAbsoluteTop methods. This will give you the position of the Button within the browser. If you want to receive the position within the HSTack, add them to the Left and Top coordinates of the HStack, respectively. Something like the following can be used:

```
HStack hStack = new HStack();
hStack.addDropHandler(new DropHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onDrop(DropEvent event) {
            Object source = event.getSource();
            if (source instanceof BaseWidget) { //This shall cover all Buttons and UI elements.
                int buttonLeftPosition = ((BaseWidget) source).getAbsoluteLeft();
                int buttonTopPosition = ((BaseWidget) source).getAbsoluteTop();
            }
        }
    });
```